# AskUbuntu permissions

Tags: discussion, comments, reputation

I was looking at the permissions available to me, and was wondering why upvoting an answer is unlocked before commenting on any thread. I understand that it's, in part, to reduce commenters who spam the site. But it's kind of a hindrance to those of us who want to help answer a question, but need more info.

Currently, I can only answer a question, not comment on it, and as such, I have to wait for someone with enough rep to ask the question I was going to, thus slowing the answering process, unless I decide to throw the rules out of the window and just post a comment in the answer area. If I do that, I'm reducing my contribution to the site, and increasing the anarchy.

Comment: Also have a look at: [How do I increase my rep?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2265/how-do-i-increase-my-rep-as-a-linux-newbie/2267?s=8|0.0000#2267)

Comment: It is a balance between frustrating new users and SPAM. Busy sites require more rep, but it is easier to gain rep. Keep contributing ;)